# Como criar um javascript para enviar um formulário para o meu e-mail?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Contenho o seguinte código HTML5:

```
<div class="form">

                    <div id="sendmessage">Sua mensagem foi enviada. Obrigado!</div>
                    <div id="errormessage"></div>
                    <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-text" id="name" placeholder="Seu nome" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Introduza pelo menos 4 caracteres" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Seu email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Por favor digite um email válido" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Assunto" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Introduza pelo menos 8 caracteres do assunto" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Por favor, escreva algo para nós" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="input-btn">Enviar Mensagem</button></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Como adicionar um javascript para me enviar essas informações, e aparecer as mensagens ali indicadas?

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer somente receber os dados deste form no seu Email, te indico essa ferramenta ridiculamente simples.
https://formspree.io/

`<form action="https://formspree.io/**seuemail**"
      method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar por javascript você pode utilizar o smtpjs (http://www.smtpjs.com/). No próprio site tem o exemplo de como utilizar e se atente para a parte de segurança que eles tem uma ferramenta para gerar um token ao invés de você colocar suas credenciais de forma aberta no código.